# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'. But 'requests' already installed

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Trying to import `'requests'`.

Has it installed via `pip3` install requests? But still, have this error.

```
C:\Users\Vikentiy>pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- ----------
certifi    2018.11.29
chardet    3.0.4
Django     2.1.7
idna       2.8
pip        19.0.2
pytz       2018.9
requests   2.21.0
setuptools 40.6.2
simplejson 3.16.0
urllib3    1.24.1
virtualenv 16.4.0

C:\Users\Vikentiy>python --version
Python 3.7.2
```

**Error Traceback:**

```
C:\Users\Vikentiy\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Vikentiy/untitled2/requeststests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/Vikentiy/untitled2/requeststests.py", line 1, in <module> import requests`
```

Comment: Where do you get this error from? Looks like you install it globally, but you might run your program in virtual environment, in this case it can't find 'requests' module

Comment: You're right. But i dont know how to install it in this particular environment. C:\Users\Vikentiy\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe  C:/Users/Vikentiy/untitled2/requeststests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vikentiy/untitled2/requeststests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests

Comment: have you created a virtual environment using python -m venv . command? where do you get your error from? What directory you are in and what command do you execute?

Comment: try executing `C:\Users\Vikentiy\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install requests`

Comment: I didn't create the envitonment. I just created a new project in PyCharm. I was in *C:\Users\Vikentiy* and the command was *pip3 install requests*. I dont undrestand the second question. Could you explain please?

Comment: Also tried     C:\Users\Vikentiy\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install requests.     And it did't help.

Comment: Solved. The code was: `import requests`  

`r = requests.get("http://google.com")`  
`print("Status:", r.status_code)`  and i typed `r = requests.get("http//google.com")`  instead of `r = requests.get("http://google.com")`.  Im sorry.

Comment: @Gahan, i actually was wrong, `-m pip install requests` solved my problem.  But do i have to always install it manually into all of environments i want to use it in? In lessons i watch the guy  just uses `pip3 install` on mac and it works for him.

Answer (score 12):

Another cause of this might be multiple Python versions installations. So if you type in your terminal:

```
pip3 install requests
```

The requests library will be automatically installed to your default python3, for example, Python3.6. However, let's say you have another Python version, for example, Python3.7, what you should do is:

```
pip3.7 install requests
```

This should solve this problem.

If you are running your code in the terminal, you should try:

```
python3.7 file_to_run.py
```

Comment: this is the best solution with multiple python environment

Answer (score 9):

Try to uninstall requests and then again install it using pip

```
pip uninstall requests
```

and again install it

```
pip install requests
```

or if you didn't get what I am saying so please visit

https://scmquest.com/resolved-importerror-no-module-named-requests-usr-bin-python-no-module-named-pip-on-macos/

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PyCharm as IDE, try closing and restarting PyCharm. Move the mouse cursor over the "requests" (with red curly line beneath it), until the red light bulb next to it show up. Select the first option in it, "Install package requests". PyCharm will take care of the installation from there.

I ran into the same issue and have tried all the solutions here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

If it is installed this will WORK:

```
c:\>python  (or on Mac/Linux "$ python")
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get("http://127.0.0.1")
<Response [200]>
```

If you see this error when running your script/IDE:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\test.py", line 1, in <module>
>
> import requests
> ImportError: No module named requests

Try:

```
python script.py
```

Answer is based on https://www.edureka.co/community/84584/python-requests-module-import-error-module-named-requests

Then the trick for me was not to start up a VirtualEnv, I actually found I was running the x64 version of python when I'd installed the requests package into the python 32 bit folder **c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages**. This is a screenshot from the internet but it shows you how to change the interpreter you're using - in my case - I need to set it to **Python 3.7.4(x86) 32 bit**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run in command prompt
and write command `pip install requests` in scripts directory

```
cd \Python27\scripts
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the exact solution which works for me, please follow this:

As like, first try to get the version of the `requests` module installed previously, this can be find by

```
pip install requests
```

Now, you will get the message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.24.0)
```

See, here the version of the requests module i.e., (2.24.0)

Now, the simple basic logic is this like you should install just the previous version of the `requests (2.24.0)`. So, you should now install `requests (2.20.0)`

For this use command:

```
pip install requests==2.20.0
```

Now, I think you can test `import requests` and this will work fine.

Further, if any error occurs then please let me know in the comments.

Thanks,
HaPpY Coding

Comment: This is truly the correct solution that works for me! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to missing request module in python package .So you can use below command to install and recheck by restarting your IDE

**`pip install requests`**

If already installed better to upgrade

**`pip install --upgrade pip`**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using venv (virtual environment), you may need to consider where it's path. for my case it was outside my project folder. So I had to first install request inside the main python's path then I recreate venv inside my project.

```
inside_your_project#python -m venv ./venv
```

Answer (score 0):

requests could be many different sub-modules so like if you are using urllib request it would be

```
import urllib.request
```

I would recommend urllib.request because it has worked well in the past.
I'm pretty sure "requests" is pretty old and very finicky and difficult to use. i was trying to access data from a server a few days ago so users wouldn't have to redownload in order to get updates and instead run code grabbed from my webserver. I tried getting requests to work but to no avail. after some digging around I found urllib which worked like a charm.

for example, this code grabs code from a webpage and executes it:

```
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://pastebin.com/raw/j5LSmvP4')
r = page.read()
exec(r.decode())
```

also when creating a StackOverflow question, I would recommend showing a code snippet or example as a visual representation to know what the answer-er is dealing with in terms of context.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you are having more than one Python installations and you have this module installed in one installation but using another for execution.

You can check the Python interpreter you are using for execution.

Run

```
pip show <module name>
```

and check the module causing issue, is in which location, this will tell you which Python installation you should use as your interpreter or else you can copy the module files manually to your current Python interpreter installation's location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually You are using an IDE like VS Code.
In case of VS Code change the "Default Interpreter Path". There error happens that there is another python version installed on your system and your IDE is using that version.
Now what to do:
Steps:

1. Find the actual python path e.g user/appdata/local/programs/python/311
2. Goto VSCode settings>python and past this path in "Default Interpreter Path"
   Done.