# I have installed requests but I still get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' (Django)

Tags: django, authentication, python-3.9

### This is what I get when I install 'requests'

If I do pip3 install requests (Requirement already satisfied),

If I do pip install requests (Requirement already satisfied),

python3.9 -mpip install requests (Requirement already satisfied),

---

It seems like I have requests already installed but still I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'"

I'm having a file with this code in my django project

```
    import requests

def client():
    credentials = {"username": "admin", "password": "123456789"}

    response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/rest-auth/login/",
                              data=credentials)

        
    print("Status Code:" , response.status_code)
    response_data = response.json()
    print(response_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client()
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54731479/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-but-requests-already-installe/54732792

Comment: You can find the answer in this link I found on that post https://scmquest.com/resolved-importerror-no-module-named-requests-usr-bin-python-no-module-named-pip-on-macos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution at this [website](https://scmquest.com/resolved-importerror-no-module-named-requests-usr-bin-python-no-module-named-pip-on-macos/)

Solution:

> python3 -m pip install --user requests

It then got installed on python3 but not 2 or less, so it would only work if you use python3.

Depends on your default version of python. mine is Python 2.7.16

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but the installed package needs to be set in settings.py file in Installed Apps part.

Comment: It had to be installed with "python3 -m pip install --user requests", after that it worked.